# How to make changes to SKActions periodically?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to change the speedOfRectangle after spawning a few rectangles(SKShapeNodes).

```
func wait(factor: CGFloat = 1) -> SKAction {
    return SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(rectHeight * speedOfRectangle * distanceBetweenRectangles / factor))
}

let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([wait(), increaseCounter, spawnAction])
let spawnSequenceForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSequence)

worldNode.runAction(spawnSequenceForever)
```

How to make changes to SKActions periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to change an action is remove the old action and create a new one. You can remove actions by removing with a "key" or simply remove all actions running on a node with `removeAllActions()`.

Changing actions while they are running has no effect until the action is completed and run again.

Hope this helped and good luck.